# how to fix tsr-detect-possible-timing-attacks potential timing attacks

Tags: javascript, typescript, tslint

I have code like this:

```
if (!confirmPassword) {
  errors.confirmPassword = DefaultValidateErrors.confirmPassword;
} else if (password && password !== confirmPassword) {
  errors.confirmPassword = DefaultValidateErrors.confirmPasswordMatch;
}
```

tslint has flagged this as tsr-detect-possible-timing-attacks which sounds correct but how do I fix it.

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a false positive and you can just suppress the lint warning.  The lint rule looks for [any variable named `password`](https://snyk.io/blog/node-js-timing-attack-ccc-ctf#timing-attacks), but a timing attack is only relevant when data unknown to the client is involved, e.g., when checking a password specified by a client trying to log in against the saved correct password.  It looks like this code is just validating a new password being set by an authenticated user.

That said, for avoiding timing attacks when they are relevant, a [web search](https://www.google.com/search?q="tsr-detect-possible-timing-attacks") found me [the rule documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint-config-security?activeTab=readme#tsr-detect-possible-timing-attacks), which links to [a post](https://snyk.io/blog/node-js-timing-attack-ccc-ctf#timing-attacks) with a suggested solution to compare two passwords in constant time using bitwise operations.  (You would think that functionality would be in a library somewhere.  Maybe it is.)

Answer (score 7):

If you are in node and version v6.6.0+, then you can use the `crypto` module's `timingSafeEqual`.

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
const isValid = crypto.timingSafeEqual(Buffer.from(password), Buffer.from(confirmPassword));
```

[Node crypto docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_timingsafeequal_a_b)